# Dart: How check for a very specific exception?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I specifically test for "file not found error" without a fuzzy-match:

[image]

If the file isn't there I want it to silently return null.  But if it's something else I want to know about it.

Comment: How is it fuzzy?